# Handling language code in URL with htaccess. Redirect according to it

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling to handle languages in my website.

So far I was handling my pages as it

```
# Mother page, no child : http://www.example.com/2-news.html
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z-]*).html$ index.php?id=$1&parent=0 [L]
# Child page : http://www.example.com/2-news_1-news-title.html    
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z-]*)_([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ index.php?id=$3&parent=$1 [L]
```

It works great like this.

Now that i want add some languages to my website, i'd like it to work this way :

- The user reach `http://www.example.com` I check is language and redirect according to it :

  - French : you stay on `http://www.example.com`
  - English : you move to `http://www.example.com/en`
  - None of the existing languages in my DB : you move to `http://www.example.com/en`

So then my URL would look like :

- `http://www.example.com/2-news.html` to `index.php?lang=fr&id=2&parent=0`.
- `http://www.example.com/en/2-news.html` to `index.php?lang=en&id=2&parent=0`.

And so `http://www.example.com/2-news_1-news-title.html`would be `index.php?lang=fr&id=1&parent=2` and `http://www.example.com/en/2-news_1-news-title.html`would be `index.php?lang=en&id=1&parent=2`.

I did this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(fr|en) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ en [L]

RewriteRule ^(fr|en)$ index.php?lang=$1&id=$2&parent=0 [L,NC,QSA]

# Level 1
RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z-]*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&id=$2&parent=0 [L,NC,QSA]

# Level 2
RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z-]*)_([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ index.php?lang=$1&id=$4&parent=$2 [L]
```

It works kinda well but not exactly like I expected. For french, which should be the root of my website, other link won't work if i don't add `fr/` before.
`http://www.example.com/fr/2-news.html` works while `http://www.example.com/2-news.html` won't.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First at your rules , this line `RewriteRule ^$ en [L]` is doing nothing , it is already done by previous rule   `RewriteRule ^$ %1 [L]`  then you should separate `fr & en` rules to achieve what you are looking for like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(fr|en) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %1 [L]


RewriteRule ^(en)$  index.php?lang=$1&id=$2&parent=0 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en)/([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z-]*).html$ index.php?lang=$1&id=$2&parent=0 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en)/([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z-]*)_([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ index.php?lang=$1&id=$4&parent=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(fr)?$  index.php?lang=fr&id=$2&parent=0 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(fr)?/?([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z-]*).html$ index.php?lang=fr&id=$2&parent=0 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(fr)?/?([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z-]*)_([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ index.php?lang=fr&id=$4&parent=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you ! Works perfectly now.
I just have to add a PHP function to be sure all my links have the good language prefix according on which language the user is.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for `Accept-language` header is useful when your clients send it within each HTTP request. Because I'm not sure about your set up environment, this is your first rule which is transformed into two rules to apply language slug (order may be important):

```
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es)/([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z-]+\.html$ index.php?lang=$1&id=$2&parent=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z-]+\.html$ index.php?lang=fr&id=$1&parent=0 [L]
```

Comment: Great ! Works well on that point ! Thank you.
I assume that my second rule would look like this :
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es)/([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z-]+\.html$ index.php?lang=$1&id=$2&parent=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-[a-zA-Z-]+\.html$ index.php?lang=fr&id=$1&parent=0 [L]

About the Accept-language I would like to redirect any user that have French or English set in their browser to root or /en. 

Right now if i set my language to english and load my website, the english is loaded in root and not root/en